# Waffle Authorization Without Any Kind Of Login

Tags: java, single-sign-on, waffle

I have a web application in the intranet and the client which is already in the intranet and has been successfully login on his/her windows computer does not want to enter any login credentials again. I have met with Waffle. As I tried its samples, it provides SSO with windows credentials, this is a plus for me. But the thing is, I don't want my clients to enter their windows credentials again, they already have successfully login to their computer, so they want to access intranet web applications without entering any kind of credentials. Could Waffle do that? Or is it a must that user have to enter windows credential again?

Answer (score 1):

From documentation, it is clear that Waffle supports what you are looking for.

You could use a Kerberos based system (NTLM + Kerberos)

Answer (score 0):

As per [Waffle's Documentation](https://github.com/dblock/waffle), Windows SSO ( NTLM or Kerberos)  is what you are looking for. Also make sure that browsers of intranet users are configured as per "[Configuring Browsers for Single Sign On](https://github.com/dblock/waffle/blob/master/Docs/ConfiguringBrowsers.md)"